# BibLaTex empty bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm working with TeXShop 3.61 and I'm currently switching from natbib to biblatex. Despite having tried for hours and read through all other entries, I still can't make it work.

*.tex Document:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Ohne-Titel}
\begin{document}
Test test test \cite{Lee2009a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

*.aux File:*

```
\relax 
\abx@aux@sortscheme{nty}
\abx@aux@cite{Lee2009a}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
```

*.bib Entry:*

```
@article{Lee2009a,
author = {Lee, Geun},
file = {:Users/JulianLeitner/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Lee - 2009 - A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy.pdf:pdf},
journal = {The Korean Journal of Defense Analysis},
number = {2},
pages = {205--218},
title = {{A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy}},
volume = {21},
year = {2009}
}
```

And here the error message:

```
 LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Lee2009a' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

 LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 6.

 [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
 (./Ohne-Titel.aux)

 LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

To compile I simply use the Macro --> applescript --> bibliography.

Any help would be highly appreciated! 
Julian

Comment: `\addbibresource{Ohne-Titel.bib}`, not `\bibliography{Ohne-Titel}`

Comment: You need to run Biber and not BibTeX. Check out [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for guidance on that. See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Works both ways (quite deliberately)

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing to Biber in the editor engine did the job!

Comment: I got the same error message when there was a syntax error in my `.bib` file such that the bibliography did not build correctly. The error log luckily told me which line was wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `biblatex` is used, the bib-file should be specified with `addbibresource{...}`.

`\bibliography` is 'deprecated` and shouldn't be used any longer.

And use `biber` after `pdflatex`, compile twice (or better three times!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Ohne-Titel.bib}
\begin{document}
Test test test \cite{Lee2009a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`Ohne-Titel.bib`

```
@article{Lee2009a,
author = {Lee, Geun},
file = {:Users/JulianLeitner/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Lee - 2009 - A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy.pdf:pdf},
journal = {The Korean Journal of Defense Analysis},
number = {2},
pages = {205--218},
title = {{A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy}},
volume = {21},
year = {2009}
}
```

[image]

Comment: While `\bibliography{<basename>}` is deprecated for `\addbibresource{<basname>.<ext>}`, it should still work here ... I'd hazard the guess that it's a problem of calling Biber and not BibTeX that is at the heart of the issue here.

Comment: @moewe: You're the `bibliography` expert here. I think it's still better to refer to `\addbibresource`, isn't it?

Comment: I certainly prefer `\addbibresource` over `\bibliography`, but there are some that like the old way of doing things. For some of the extra functionality (access to remote locations etc.) `\addbibresource` is required, but most people can get what they need from `\bibliography`.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for explanation -- I changed to `shouldn't` be used in the post

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is it possible to use (an adpatation of) your code above with LuaLaTeX ? For now, it does not produce any Reference, and it is written [**Lee2009a**] in place of the `\cite` command after the compilation. I could have missed something about how doing a "good" compilation...

Comment: @Nicolas: I just compiled the code above with `LuaLaTeX`. The citation is `[1]`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for the answer. This is strange: it does not produce the same result for me. What about the `.bib` file ? Did you compile it, or is it enough to save it in the same repertory as the main file ? How do you explain the difference (I just cut/pasted your code) ?

Comment: I have the `.bib` file in the same directory, but that shouldn't matter actually. Did you run `biber` at all at the end of the first compilation, then `lualatex` twice? At the moment, I don't have a clue what's going wrong with your compilation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I ran the main file with Biber and then twice with LuaLaTeX, but each time I ran with LuaLaTeX, there was the error message "Package biblatex Warning: File 'test02.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2
.6.".

Comment: @Nicolas: Either it is a misunderstanding or an error: `lualatex main.tex ; biber main.aux ; lualatex main.tex ; lualatex main.tex`, if the main file is called `main.tex`, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Now you write this sequence like this, I remember having seen it in some other posts without understanding it. So precisely, where do I write the sequence `lualatex main.tex;` `biber main.aux;``lualatex main.tex;` `lualatex main.tex` (I use MiKTeX 2.9 and write my documents with TeXworks if it matters...) ?

Comment: @Nicolas: I assume this is incorporated in TeXWorks as `click` on the button with `lualatex` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There indeed are LuaLaTeX and Biber (that I've manually added following the instructions that a user posted on tex.stackexchange), and I ran my main file with them in the order you indicated to me. The error message appeared during the compilation of the main file with LuaLaTeX just after the one with Biber...

Comment: @Nicolas: Well, I fear I can't provide help on this. I neither use MikTeX nor such editors. I compile on console and am quite happy with that

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK, no problem. I thank you anyway for the time you spent on my problem.

Comment: @Nicolas: I am pretty sure it's some TeXWorks configuration issue.

Comment: @moewe Since you seem to be the bibliography expert here, can I ask you what do you think about my problem please ? I cut/pasted the code of Christian Hupfer and compiled (I use MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXWorks) with LuaLaTeX, Biber and twice with LuaLaTeX, and got the error message "Package biblatex Warning: File 'test02.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2 .6.". I did not see this kind of error in other posts here. I think that Christian Hupfer is right when he says that it should be some TeXWorks configuration issue.

Comment: @Nicolas Sounds like a version mismatch of `biblatex` and Biber. Update both packages, since you use MikTeX run the Update Manager in both Admin and User mode (you might even have to do this twice to update all packages). Then delete the temporary files and try again. You can check the configuration issue in the post this question is a duplicate of, for the update stuff see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your answer. I've updated and synchronizd MiKTeX. But as I am both User and Admin, I've just do it as Admin; besides, I do not know how to update+synchronize as User... Then I ran with LuaLaTeX, Biber and both LuaLaTeX: each time, there was the error message `! Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found..`, but my bibliography is OK now. So I have a new problem that is discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309140/after-miktex-update-when-using-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys. Thanks again for your help!