# Biblatex (and biber) empty bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

As a test, I've got this most simple `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{src.bib}
\begin{document}
Test test test \cite{abc}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `src.bib`:

```
@article{abc,  
    title={abc},  
    author={def}
}
```

yet the result is :

[image: result]

The text between square brackets is simple the argument I call in `\cite` and the output logs a warning:

> warning empty bibliography

I assume it doesn't work because of the empty bibliography but I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. The `.tex` file and the `.bib` file are in the same directory. My editor is TeXstudio.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305381/biblatex-empty-bibliography) does also not help and omitting the backend part gives the same result

Comment: Bib you run the normal cycle `pdflatex +biber+pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: I simply click on the `Build & View` button in TexStudio

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document, so that the complete sequence is LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with getting your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to configure your editor run Biber and produce the desired bibliography and citations? If not, what did you try (how did you configure your editor? how did you try to run Biber?) and how did this not work for you (do you get Biber errors?)?

Comment: @moewe I had to go to do three clicks after adding a book, paper, .... The first was to build, the second was going to tools, bibliography (f8) and then the third compile again

Comment: OK. In that case I think your question is a duplicate of the canonical "you need to run BibTeX/Biber again" question.